# Определить нажавшего Inline кнопку

Tags: python, telebot

Я программирую на python с библиотекой telebot. Хотел бы узнать, как определить того, кто нажал кнопку. Я хочу, чтобы кнопка срабатывала только в том случае, если ее нажимает создатель. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так можно

```
@bot.message_handler()
def reserve(message: types.Message):
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(InlineKeyboardButton("text", callback_data="prefix:data"))
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="text", reply_markup=markup)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.from_user.id == "your_id" and call.data.startswith("prefix:"))
def func(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    bot.answer_callback_query(call.id)
    ...
```

Comment: Уже разобрался, но все же спасибо! Задал новый вопрос, ответь, если знаешь, пожалуйста!)